# How to select a process (of multiprocess) by the process name?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was wondering how to select a process by its given name?

code:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    while True:
        print 'foo'
        sleep(50)

for i in xrange(3):
    name ='name '+str(i)
    t = process(name=name,target=foo)
    t.start()
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your quesition.

```
procs = {}
for i in xrange(3):
    name ='name '+str(i)
    t = process(name=name,target=foo)
    t.start()
    procs[name] = t
```

Now `procs` contains `process` by its name. You can access some process by `procs['name0']` ...

BTW, `multiprocess` works? or `multiprocessing` is right?

Comment: yep, i thought maybe there was a simple call to process by name that i missed insteed of making a dictionary. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple processes may be given the same name.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) So any two-way mapping between names and processes is a logic you impose, not enforced by the library.

As a consequence, I think your only option is to keep a catalog (i.e. a dictionary).

By the way, I may be biased by your snippet, but I would expect a Pool is more suited to your needs.

Comment: a dictionary in my case will be easier than a pool, thanks for the reference. thanks anyway.

Comment: +1. Thanks, It's the reason why my answer is a solution.